# Losing local info between deploys only if device unplugged xamarin

Tags: file, xamarin, save, local

I am trying to read and write from a local file in a simple app on xamarin, to move on towards what might be a more ambitius app. I achieve to write in a local file and read from it. It works great until I unplug the phone and re-plug it to debug my app again.
The funny thing is that when I rund the standalone app it runs great, I can retrieve the info. If I stop and play in visual studio many times, it also works great, I can retrieve the info from the saved file.
However, if I unplug the device and plug it again for debug, I can't retrieve the local's file saved info. I tried with [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage/pulls), and with the [.Net System.IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=net-5.0)

With PCLStorage, the retrieved info is blank, is if nothing was written before, and with the .Net System.IO, it gives an exception when reading the file saying that it could not be found `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "fullPathToMyFile"`

This would break all the saved data of the local device incase the app needed to be debugged.
Below the code, with System.IO, and the PCLStorage code commented, but in both cases working apart from the specific case of unplugging and replugging the device to debug.

Take into account that `updateStoredItems()` that is the method that writes data is only called when items are added or erased. When the app starts, items are read from `void addUSerStoredItems(ObservableCollection<Item> items)` .

I got checked the option "Preserve application data cache on device between deploys", which seems to work, until you unplug the device.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Accountable.Models;
using Accountable.Views;
using PCLStorage;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Accountable.ViewModels {
    public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }
        string _fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "notes.txt");

        public void updateStoredItems() {
            //IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            //IFolder folder = await rootFolder.GetFolderAsync("MySubFolder");
            //IFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("answer.txt");
            string fileText = ItemSerializer.SerializeObject(Items);
            //await file.WriteAllTextAsync(fileText);
            File.WriteAllText(_fileName, fileText);
            Debug.Write(fileText);
        }

        public ItemsViewModel() {
            Title = "Browse";
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewItemPage, Item>(this, "AddItem", async (obj, item) => {
                var newItem = item as Item;
                Items.Add(newItem);
                updateStoredItems();
                await DataStore.AddItemAsync(newItem);
            });

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ItemDetailPage, Item>(this, "DeleteItem", async (obj, item) => {
                Items.Remove(item);
                updateStoredItems();
                await DataStore.RemoveItemAsync(item);
            });
        }

        void addUSerStoredItems(ObservableCollection<Item> items) {
            //IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            //IFolder folder = await rootFolder.GetFolderAsync("MySubFolder");
            //IFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("answer.txt");
            string storedItems = File.ReadAllText(_fileName);//await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
            //debug
            Debug.WriteLine("STORED ITEMS:");
            Debug.WriteLine(storedItems);
            List<Item> itemsToAdd = null;
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Item>));
            using (StringReader textReader = new StringReader(storedItems)) {
                itemsToAdd = (List<Item>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            }
            itemsToAdd.ForEach(itemToAdd => items.Add(itemToAdd));
        }

        async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand() {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            IsBusy = true;

            try {
                Items.Clear();
                var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
                foreach (var item in items) {
                    Items.Add(item);
                }
                //List<Item> itemList = items.Cast<Item>().ToList();
                addUSerStoredItems(Items);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex); //here file not found exception is thrown with the System.IO attempt
            }
            finally {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ItemSerializer {
        public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize) {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());

            using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter()) {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: There is a workaround, if visual studio is restarted after the device unplug, the local file data is preserved. In case it helps anyone reading this.
By the way I am using Visual Studio 2017 15.9.14.

Comment: When you unplug the device, have you close all the app and restart?

Comment: you mean in the phone, right?. Close the app I think so, I can check that though, but I am not clear about what do you mean by restart.

Comment: When you unplug the device, close the app on the device and restart the device to check the reading and writting. When you plug the device, use the VS to start debug and check the reading and writting.

Comment: Restarting VS works. Restart the phone might also work. Both solutions a bit anoying and not ver good/from root solutions, but I guess It can be handled once you get used to it. Moreover the exposure to lose all your local data is huge. I will check your suggestion out to check if that also works. Many thanks

Comment: When your unplug or plug the device, it would get something wrong for the data if you still run the app. We do not suggest to do that. Restart the phone would be helpful. Glad to help.

Comment: What I think I did is click stop in VS or close the app which seems to be the same, to stop execution. Then if unplugged the next plug mun run in debug mode produces the local data reset/file undetect. It is expected that if you unplugg in playmode without stop or without closing the app to have problems. But I will check this once more and check if restarting the device solves the problem as restarting VS. Thanks for your help

Comment: restarting the device also works to avoid the problem